# JPEG compressing without DLLs

Tags: c++, c, windows, jpeg

I want to convert raw RGB image data (I could add BMP header if necessary) to JPEG on Windows. Is it possible to do so without DLLs?
I tried statically compiling IJG jpeglib, but I have VC++ 9, and it only works for VC++ 10

Answer (score 2):

Use GDI+ to save the image to a file.  For example, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535407(VS.85).aspx for how to save to a file.  Specify the JPEG encoder.  To load the image into the Image class, you can use the Bitmap class (inherits from Image).  Several methods are available: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536286(VS.85).aspx.

GDI+ comes with Windows XP and newer and can be redistributed for older Windows versions.  So you probably won't need to bundle anything newer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, either write your own JPEG encoder or use other lib, like OpenCV. Just take care of its licensing requirements when you static link them

Answer (score 0):

The [reference implementation](http://www.ijg.org) is freely available and usable for any kind of project.

Also, you can write JPEG images using GDI+ (without any extra libraries that Windows doesn't already have anyway).

For that, create a `Bitmap`, `LockBits` to get a writable pointer, write the data, and `UnlockBits`.

If the image was captured from OpenGL, you must `RotateFlip` it, or it will be upside down.

Now create a `PropertyItem` and fill in the metadata, then `SetPropertyItem` on your `Bitmap`.

Create and initialize an `EncoderParameters`, here you set the quality and whatnot.

Lastly, call `Save` on your `Bitmap`.